# Multiple JPA repositories when I want operations to persist across several levels in the database hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm using spring hibernate and JPA to model a system where there are four levels in the database hierarchy, each with one to many relationships meaning: GreatGrandParent (GGP) has a one to many with the GrandParent (GP), the GP has a one to many with the Parent (P) and P has a one to many with the Child (C).

I want to be able to persist/update a GP/P/C entity and have it cascade up and down the tree. I also need to be able to retrieve the lower level entities by their parents.

The way I currently have it implemented is with a repository for each of the classes. When I want to persist a GP my code looks roughly like this

```
    public ParentEntity persistParent( final UUID GrandParentId,
                                                     final Parent parent )
    {

        final GrandParent grandParentEntity = GPRepository.findById( GrandParentId );

        parent.setGrandParent( grandParent );

        return parentRepository.save( parent );
    }
```

and when I want to retrieve a child entity it looks like this

```
    public ParentEntity findParentByGrandParent( final GrandParent grandParent,
                                                     final Parent parent )
    {

        return parentRepository.findParentByGrandParent( grandParent );
    }
```

This approach works fine. However, some have commented that I should just have one top level GGPRepository, to handle all of my persist/update operations, and then use `EntityManager` to make a custom SQL query to retrieve sub entities.

Is one approach better than the other? Why so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *However, some have commented that I should just have one top level GGPRepository, to handle all of my persist/update operations, and then use EntityManager to make a custom SQL query to retrieve sub entities* Ignore them

Comment: @AlanHay so its best to just interact with the repositories directly?